# Spawn in a fix position 2D Game

Tags: unity-game-engine, photon

I am trying to do a multiplayer game and I have a problem with spawning prefabs. I want this prefabs to be spawn in 2 fix position but I don't understand why my script doesn't work because when I start the game the objects are spawn in one position. I created an empty game object( I named it Spawner and added the script) and added 2 game objects ( Position1 , Position2 ) as Childs. The prefab is spawn in the position of the Spawner and not position 1 and 2 . 
Here is the script I used. Also do I have to add to it PhotonView and Photon Transform ? and something with PunRPC?

```css
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SpawnPosition : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject[] powersPrefab;
    public Transform[] points;
    public float beat= (60/130)*2;
    private float timer;




    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (timer > beat)
        {
            GameObject powers = Instantiate(powersPrefab[Random.Range(0, 2)]);
            powers.transform.localPosition = Vector2.zero;
            timer -= beat;

        }
        timer += Time.deltaTime;
    }
}
```

Comment: You always set `powers.transform.localPosition = Vector2.zero`, since the object is Instantiated on root level without a parent this equals setting its absolute position .... you always set it to the Unity origin ....

Comment: so I should erased this line of code?

Comment: This won't make any difference since this happens by default in Instantiate anyway .... I don't see where you use any position of a child object of the spawner here ... and also: If this is for multiplayer ... you are currently spawning objects only on one client and not telling the other clients that something was spawned ... no photon expert but you would need something like NetworkInstantiate or so ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
void Update() {
        if (timer > beat) {
            GameObject powers = Instantiate(powersPrefab[Random.Range(0, 2)]);
            powers.transform.localPosition = points[Random.Range(0, points.Length)].position;
            timer -= beat;

        }
        timer += Time.deltaTime;
    }
}
```

You are not assigning right position, and since they are parentless `power.transform.position = Vector2.zero` means that power's global position would always 0,0,0. So you must assign it as I wrote above, and it's also randomized.

Comment: I get this error : IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
SpawnPosition.Update ()  and it refers at line GameObject powers = Instantiate(powersPrefab[Random.Range(0, 2)]); -------- what I should change?

Comment: Looks like powersPrefab array is empty, or there is only 1 object, so fill it from unity inspector with your prefabs

Comment: And also I suggest you to always name container objects(e.g arrays or lists) plural words, It's better to be GameObject powerPrefabs[] for better undestanding the code

Answer (score 1):

You always set

```c#
powers.transform.localPosition = Vector2.zero
```

The object is instantiated on root level without a parent this equals setting its absolute position .... you always set it to the Unity origin.

---

You probably wanted to spawn it at the position of on of the elements in `points` like e.g.:

```c#
var powers = Instantiate(
    powersPrefab[Random.Range(0, powersPrefab.Length)], 
    points[Random.Range(0, points.Length)].position, 
    Quaternion.identity
);
```

see [`Instantiate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html) for available overloads.

---

However as you also state this is for multiplayer so you shouldn't use `Instantiate` **at all** since this only spawns this object on this client but not on others. You should probably rather make sure that this spawner is only running on one of your clients and use [`PhotonNetwork.Instantiate`](https://doc.photonengine.com/en-us/pun/v2/gameplay/instantiation) instead.

Something like e.g.

```c#
public class SpawnPosition : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject[] powersPrefab;
    public Transform[] points;
    public float beat= (60/130)*2;
    private float timer;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        // only run this if you are the master client
        if(!PhotonNetwork.isMasterClient) return;

        if (timer > beat)
        {
            // spawn the prefab object over network
            // Note: This requires you to also reference the prefabs in Photon as spawnable object
            Instantiate(
                powersPrefab[Random.Range(0, 2)].name, 
                points[Random.Range(0, points.Length)].position, 
                Quaternion.identity, 
                0
            );
            timer -= beat;
        }
        timer += Time.deltaTime;
    }
}
```