# Spawn objects don't sync

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to do a multiplayer game using photon and when I try to spawn objects near my player, they don't sync the same for both players. What I should add in the inspector (Already both objects that need to be spawn have `PhotonView` and `PhotonView Transform`). What I should add to my script?

```css
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Photon.Pun;

public class SpawnFix : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject[] powersPrefab;
    public Transform[] points;
    public float beat = (60 / 130) * 2;
    private float timer;




    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame

      [PunRPC]
    void Update()
    {
        if (timer > beat)
        {
            GameObject powers = Instantiate(powersPrefab[Random.Range(0, 2)]);
            powers.transform.localPosition = points[Random.Range(0, points.Length)].position;
            timer -= beat;

        }
        timer += Time.deltaTime;
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spawn in a fix position 2D Game](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61325045/spawn-in-a-fix-position-2d-game/61325211#61325211)

Answer (score 1):

Given the similarity of your code:

Was exactly this question not already asked and answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61325045/spawn-in-a-fix-position-2d-game/61325211#61325211)? (Only that there you accepted the stupid answer ^^)

---

Anyway

well ... that's not how [`[PunRPC]`](https://doc.photonengine.com/en-us/pun/v2/gameplay/rpcsandraiseevent) works. It would need to be invoked via the network somewhere e.g. via

```c#
var photonView = PhotonView.Get(this);
photonView.RPC("Update", RpcTarget.All);
```

**HOWEVER**, you definitely wouldn't want to synchronize the `Update` method itself every frame but rather only the spawning.

---

You probably should rather use [`PhotonNetwork.Instantiate`](https://doc.photonengine.com/en-us/pun/v2/gameplay/instantiation)

```c#
public class SpawnFix : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject[] powersPrefab;
    public Transform[] points;
    public float beat = (60 / 130) * 2;
    private float timer;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        // only run on the master client
        if(!PhotonNetwork.isMasterClient) return;

        if (timer > beat)
        {
            PhotonNetwork.Instantiate(
                powersPrefab[Random.Range(0, 2)].name, 
                points[Random.Range(0, points.Length)].position, 
                Quaternion.idendity, 
            0);

            timer -= beat;

        }
        timer += Time.deltaTime;
    }
}
```

For this the prefabs need to be registered in the Photon as spawnable objects.

Comment: I get this errors: The name 'powers' does not exist in the current context,The name 'quaternion' does not exist in the current context,'PhotonNetwork' does not contain a definition for 'isMasterClient'

Comment: Well all of these are obviously typos: The first shuold only use the position not assign it to any transform, the second is `Quaternion` and finally `IsMasterClient`

Comment: I imported again photon , still getting this error with IsMasterClient , idk what to do

Comment: Actually it depends what are you using? For PUN it is [`isMasterClient`](https://doc-api.photonengine.com/en/pun/v1/class_photon_network.html#af498064a6019a6c69e875bd64db40216) for PUN2 it is [`IsMasterClient`](https://doc-api.photonengine.com/en/pun/v2/class_photon_1_1_pun_1_1_photon_network.html#a57f4f9f3db3f4e69d7262affd7b673ee)